# Magnet and Delete button from Not Enough Items doesn't appear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Magnet and Delete button won't show on my server but everything else shows time, gamemode, rain, etc. This mod works for me on my worlds flawlessly. Any tips or tricks to get these button to show & work on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Go into NEI options in the botton left corner and navigate into Inventory. If you want all buttons to appear, simply enter cheat mode and its done. If you want configured buttons to appear, enter utility mode and select which buttons to appear.